# Collapse daily data frame down to weekly data frame in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows:

```
     office string_date   A   B  C   D    E
1:      11  2010-06-01    0   0  1   0    0
2:      11  2010-06-02    0   0  0   1    0
3:      11  2010-06-03    0   0  0   1    0
4:      11  2010-06-04    0   0  0   1    0
5:      11  2010-06-05    0   0  0   1    0
6:      11  2010-06-06    0   1  0   0    0
7:      11  2010-06-07    0   1  0   0    0
8:      11  2010-06-08    0   1  0   0    0
9:      11  2010-06-09    0   1  0   0    0
10:     11  2010-06-10    0   1  0   0    0
11:     11  2010-06-11    0   1  0   0    0
12:     11  2010-06-12    0   1  0   0    0
```

I need to aggregate the sums of each column by the week, not the day as it is listed. So I would be left with each week for each office, with the sums of each column. The first line would be...

```
office  week   A  B  C  D  E
  11     1     0  2  1  4  0
  11     2     .............
```

I am using something like:

```
agg <- aggregate(list(data$A, data$B, data$C, data$D, data$E), list(office = data$office, Date = data$string_date), sum)
```

But of course this doesn't have any ability to collapse the dates down by week. Also, these dates are strings, not currently posix.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain this is a duplicate. Do you know how to search? You would of course want to convert to Date-class at least for the construction of a week vector.

Comment: Great way to welcome people to coding...bring the attitude and not the help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=aggregate+data+frame+week

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new column called `week` using the `week` function and then do a split-apply-combine on that:

```
DT[,week := week(string_date)][, lapply(.SD, sum), by = "office,week", .SDcols = 3:6]
```

Or in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
DT %>%
  group_by(office, week = week(string_date)) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum), -string_date)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you are using the `data.table` package based on your print out.

Comment: nice! I see the sums are by week for all offices. Can we get this per office?

Comment: Ah your second one does it. Thank you :)