# How to create a new dataframe with collapsed rows based on date and another vector from a prior dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with historical personal weightlifting information and I have several entries for the same exercise on the same date. I'm trying to collapse these exercises to one row but I want the vector "Total Weight" to include the sum of all three rows for said vector from the prior dataframe.

For example, this is the initial dataframe:

```
Date                Workout.Name    Exercise.Name               Set.Order  TotalWeight
6/29/2017 9:50      Chest 1         barbell bench press         0          55      

6/29/2017 9:50      Chest 1         barbell bench press         1          55      

6/29/2017 9:50      Chest 1         barbell bench press         2          55      

7/4/2017 10:23      Chest 1         barbell bench press         0          55      

7/4/2017 10:23      Chest 1         barbell bench press         1          55      

7/4/2017 10:23      Chest 1         barbell bench press         2          55

11/14/2017 1:22     Chest 1         barbell bench press         0          80      

11/14/2017 1:22     Chest 1         barbell bench press         1          80      

11/14/2017 1:22     Chest 1         barbell bench press         2          80
```

And this is the dataframe I would like to create:

```
Date                Workout.Name    Exercise.Name               Set.Order  TotalWeight
6/29/2017 9:50      Chest 1         barbell bench press         0          165
7/4/2017 10:23      Chest 1         barbell bench press         0          165
11/14/2017 1:22     Chest 1         barbell bench press         0          240
```

Could anyone tell me what my script should look like in order to make this new dataframe? I imagine it would leverage some piping and goup_by() in the dplyr package but I can't figure it out. Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just aggregate by date:

```
aggregate(dat$TotalWeight, by=list(Date=dat$Date), FUN=sum)
```

Where `dat` is your original database. Notice that this will dismiss the other variables (Workout.Name, Exercise.Name). To keep them, just pass them as arguments in the list.

```
aggregate(dat$TotalWeight, by=list(Date=dat$Date,
                                   Workout.Name= dat$Workout.Name,
                                   Exercise.Name=dat$Exercise.Name), FUN=sum)
```

For further reference, aggregate is a wrapper for apply, which is more general. Also this question has been asked before. 
[Here is another way using apply or the dplyr package.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36730504/collapse-daily-data-frame-down-to-weekly-data-frame-in-r)